# Assign text values to JSON Data

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am getting JSON data from an url like this:

```
... 
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("jsonCell") as! CeldaGeo
    var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
    cell.cofradia.text = dict["cofradia"] as? String
    cell.calle.text = dict["calle"] as? String
    cell.id.text = dict["idc"] as? String
    cell.tipo.text = dict["tipo"] as? String
    cell.latitud.text = dict["latitud"] as? String
    cell.longitud.text = dict["longitud"] as? String
    cell.tipo.text = dict["tipo"] as? String
    let tipo = dict["tipo"] as? String
    let id = dict["idc"] as? String
    cell.imagen.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://elpenitente.playcofrade.com/img/escudos/\(tipovalue)/\(id!).jpg")!)

    return cell
```

After, I load an image from an url which changes depending the other values. 
My problem is, the value `tipo`is a number (1,2,3) but in the url it should be text. For example `1` will be `cofradias`. How can I assign this values so that I can use them later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctely. You only need to have a separate dictionary mapping the ids with its strings.

```
let imageNames = ["1":"cofradias","2":"string2","3":"string3"]
```

Then in your code you'll use it like:

```
let id = dict["idc"] as? String
let tipo = dict["tipo"] as? String
let imageName = imageNames[tipo!]

cell.imagen.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://elpenitente.playcofrade.com/img/escudos/cofradias/\(imageName!)/\(id!).jpg")!)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain that point, I think now I know what I have to do, the only thing is that that `imageNames` would be another variable value like this... `cell.imagen.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://elpenitente.playcofrade.com/img/escudos/\(imageName!)/\(anothervalue!).jpg")!)` Is that right?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by `imageNames` would be another variable. Would you please update your question to add more description?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry my code and problem was wrong at first, I have updated everything.

Comment: for what you change I'd change my answer by just puting tipo instead of id.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. and let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: Thanks, I will let you know when I can program it

Comment: Let me ask you something, how can I do something similar to sign a value to a button?

Comment: You mean A button title right? it's simple because it's two separate things. 1) get the value out of the json and put it in a variable(the same way we got the id and tipo).
2) assign that value to a button title. `button.setTitle(value, forState: UIControlState.Normal) `

Comment: I need a button that when it is pressed passes a number to the next controller. I am looking for the way to assign the number to the button. I already have prepareforsegue

Comment: You just need to get the number form json and put it in a instance variable, then when the user press that button and trigger prepareforsegue you assign this number to its corresponding in the destination vc.